# Android AsyncTask : UI operation not working in Android from Background Task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-custom-view, background-process

What i want :

- wait for connection. Until the connection is received, display a
  blank screen
- as soon as connected, set the current view to a custom view ( using `setContentView()` ). This I'm trying to do from Background Thread( `AsyncTask` )
- Then after that I'll keep accepting the points from client and keep updating them on UI thread. For this I'm accepting points from client and  sending to `publishProgess()`

But for some reason, the second step itself isn't working.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  ServerSocket server;
    public  Socket       socket;
    public  Slate        slate ;
    private Paint        mPaint;
    public static MainActivity context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        (new ServerTask()).execute();
    }



    public static MainActivity getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public void start_slate(){
        slate = new Slate(this);
        slate.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        setContentView(slate);
    }

    public class Slate extends View {
    .....
    .....
       draw(){
       ....
       ....
       }
    } /*custom drawing view*/
}
```

**Background Task**

```
/*Background Task*/
class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Action, Void>
{

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;
    private Action action;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(MainActivity.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ObjectInputStream stream;

        try{
            mainActivity.get().server = new ServerSocket(3107);
            mainActivity.get().socket = mainActivity.get().server.accept();
            stream = new ObjectInputStream(mainActivity.get().socket.getInputStream());

            MainActivity.getContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.getContext().start_slate();
                }
            }); /*BUT THE VIEW IS NOT CHANGING*/

            while(true)
            {
                if(isCancelled()){
                    break;
                }
                action = (Action)stream.readObject();
                publishProgress(action);
            }
        }catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Action... actions) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(actions);
        ((mainActivity.get()).slate).draw(actions[0]);
    }/*this will send the co-ordinates to current drawing view*/

}
```

NOTE : even if i try to set the view in `onProgressUpdate()` , it still does not happen.
It happens only in `onPostExecute()`. But I don't want that because, after changing the view, I still have to accept coordinates (The while loop part)

Comment: You should always update the UI in main thread like setting the views. In second step you are doing it from background, but it should do it in main thread.

Comment: You aren't allowed to update the UI from anything other than the UI thread.  Any calls to do so need to happen in onPostExecute, or in publishProgress.

Comment: Also NEVER have a static reference to the activity in the activity.  That's a 100% memory leak, leaking the entire screen.

Comment: Also NEVER while(true) in an async task.  There's only 1 async task thread per app.  If you need to infinitely loop, use a Thread.

Comment: The right way to run this is have a thread which is passed the Slate it needs to send commands to.  It shouldn't need to know about the Activity at all, just the view.  And any UI updates will need to be done on the UI thread of course.  If it needs to run something on the UI thread pass it a handler to the main thread rather than the Activity